# Difference in Security of PHP Scripts: Embedded in HTML or Separate File?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, security, lamp

The title pretty much says it all.  Is it better to have the PHP script embedded into the HTML page, or to have a separate PHP script file?  Which is more secure and ***why***?  In looking on this SE, I've seen a lot of posts about how to do it one way or the other, but not much on comparing them.

I'm using LAMP and Wordpress, but the WordpressSE folks said that since this is a PHP question, better to ask it here than there.

UPDATE: Ok, 5 downvotes in the first hour tells me this was not a good question.  Is the answer obvious?  Is the answer elsewhere on SE?  Is this really that dumb of a question?  Sorry for wasting everyone's time, I'm just trying to figure this out after searching over the past few days.  Perhaps I'm not asking the right question.

Comment: There is no difference in security. The true benefit comes from decoupling the HTML from the PHP where you can.

Comment: @JayBlanchard What do you mean by decoupling?  To me, decoupling means that the PHP script is in a separate file, but clearly I'm wrong on that.

Comment: In this case the decoupling comes from removing as much PHP as you can from your HTML code which often means separate files.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Not sure I follow.  Could you please clarify?  Your first comment says there is no difference between these two methods, but also says that there is benefit in decoupling, i.e. using a separate file.  Does that mean the benefit of using a separate file is something other than security?  If so, what is the benefit?

Comment: Maintenance and the ability to make rapid changes to code when needed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there are much security impact in where php is placed however, it does have considerations on areas of code for:

1. Readability
2. Testability
3. Structure

Based on your question either in .html or .php, it is on server side so it is important to ensure that server configurations or `.htaccess`. Read more about `.htaccess` configurations in [hiding](http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php) php security.

However, be caution with form processing, the following links are guidelines and references to understand possible risks.

1. [List of security measures in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/security.php)
2. [Form processing in PHP](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html)